# 画像を比率を保ったまま端数なく縮小するパーセンテージの求め方

Tags: アルゴリズム

ヘタすると小学生レベルの計算なのかもしれないのですが、
例えば `128x80` の画像があったとして、
これが丁度縦横端数なく縮小できるパーセンテージを求める公式のようなモノはありますでしょうか？

Google Sheetsで下記のように一覧を出して求めてもさして時間はかからなかったのですが、よい方法があれば知りたいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 追記：本当にやりたいこと

比率を保ったまま縮小をしたいです。
ツールとしてはMac標準搭載のPreview.appを想定しています。
下記画像からもわかる通り、パーセンテージを入力するツールではなくヨコ：タテどちらかの数値を入れると、勝手にもう片方の数値を計算してくれていますが、このときもう片方の（自動計算された）数値に端数が出ない方法を探しています。（できるだけ多く候補を出したいです。）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

小学校の算数で習う[最大公約数](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%80%E5%A4%A7%E5%85%AC%E7%B4%84%E6%95%B0)でしょうか？

`128`と`80`の最大公約数は`16`なのであとは`128x80`を最大公約数で割った`8x5`の任意倍数ということでしょうか。

Comment: はじめ最大公約数かと思ったのですが、今回の図にある96x60の60は16の倍数ではないですよね。

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi さん、倍率は任意なのでしょうか？ つまり`15/16`倍による`120x75`も解とみなすかどうか。その辺り質問文が不明確です。

Comment: おっしゃる通りですね。質問に追記しました。

Comment: なるほど。`8x5`なので、8ずつ、5ずつ増えていく一覧をGoogle Sheetsで一覧にすれば簡単ですね。

Answer (score 3):

128と80の公約数は、1を除けば [2, 4, 8, 16] です。
これらの公約数の逆数の倍数が、端数の生じない縮小倍率のリストにならないでしょうか？

2: 1/2
4: 1/4, 2/4, 3/4
8: 1/8, 2/8, ... 7/8
16: 1/16, 2/16, ... 15/16